# Magento 1.9.2.4 Supported Platforms

Tags: magento-1.9

I am working with v1.9.2.4, does this support PHP v7 and Ubuntu 16.04?  If not, what is the highest supported OS and PHP version 1.9.2.4 will cleanly install on?

Comment: https://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

https://www.mkwd.net/magento-1-9-system-requirements/

Answer (score 0):

While is comment is technically correct, it's kinda unhelpful. There are solutions to getting Magento 1.x to work for php 7.

Here is an extension you could try if you really have your heart set on 1.x

https://github.com/Inchoo/Inchoo_PHP7